# How to encode RSA private key for reduce

Tags: python, base64, rsa, encode, private-key

I'm developing a blockchain system with python flask. I use RSA keys(size = 2048) for wallet. I use base64 for reduce size of private key but it still too long

```
rsaObj = RSA.generate(2048)
privateKey = rsaObj.exportKey()

print privateKey
# output
"""
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

print base64.b64encode(privateKey)
# output
"""
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
"""
```

I want to encode private key and reduce size for give it to user because of private key is too long.

Comment: What do you mean by reduce size?  A private key has a certain amount of information in it, so there’s an information theory argument that it can’t be shortened.  Encoding it in to a string that has more possible characters at each position can make the string “shorter” (e.g. from base 10 to base 36), but it’s sill has the same amount of information in it.  And there’s not much more you can do beyond base 64 or so, since there’s no _that_ many printable characters unless you start getting silly.

Comment: Private key is part of key pair you should never tell any one. You can share only public part. Why you need to give private part to user?

Comment: @DougI mean encode private key and get shorter

Comment: @AmaroVita I know. The user who create wallet will get private key, I dont share it

Comment: The text in your `privateKey` between `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` is _already_ encoded with Base64.

Comment: Just decoding the base64 allows you to shorten the lenght to 1193 bytes. Unfortunately it can no longer be displayed or printed because it may contain any 8 bit byte, including non printable ones.

Comment: First off, elliptic curve private keys can be much shorter than RSA private keys. Secondly, the minimal RSA private key is the modulus and the decrypt exponent, which is much less information than this private key format. Thirdly, you may transmit using binary; if it must be readable then there are denser encoding formats such as base85 or even more. It all depends entirely on the details of how the components of your system will communicate, which you've not provided.